# Adding 1 hours to time stamp columns in Pyspark data frame

Tags: python, pyspark

In `pyspark` I have a column called `test_time`. This is a `timestamp` column.

The column has a records like below.

```
2017-03-12 03:19:51.0
2017-03-12 03:29:51.0
```

Now I want to add `1 hour` to the records in the `test_time` columns.

Result:

```
2017-03-12 04:19:51.0
2017-03-12 04:29:51.0
```

How can I achieve my result.

I treied like below

```
df['test_time'] = df['test_time'].apply(lambda x: x - pd.DateOffset(hours=1))
```

Got the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Comment: You might find your answer here: [Apply a function to a single column of a csv in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977625/apply-a-function-to-a-single-column-of-a-csv-in-spark)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be very easy once you convert it to a UTC timestamp. Here is one way to do it :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_utc_timestamp,from_utc_timestamp
from datetime import timedelta

## Create a dummy dataframe
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('1997-02-28 10:30:00',)], ['t'])

## Add column to convert time to utc timestamp in PST
df2 = df.withColumn('utc_timestamp',to_utc_timestamp(df.t,"PST"))

## Add one hour with the timedelta function
df3 = df2.map(lambda x: (x.t,x.utc_timestamp+timedelta(hours=1))).toDF(['t','new_utc_timestamp'])

## Convert back to original time zone and format
df4 = df3.withColumn('new_t',from_utc_timestamp(df3.new_utc_timestamp,"PST"))
```

The "new_t" column in df4 is your required column converted back to the appropriate time zone according to your system.

Comment: This solution is correct except the part where you trying to map a dataframe (df2.map) which is not possible .You need to convert that df into rdd and then apply map function on that. `df3 = df2.rdd.map(lambda x: (x.t,x.utc_timestamp+timedelta(hours=1))).toDF(['t','new_utc_timestamp'])`

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do this in pyspark is:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions expr
df = df.withColumn("test_time_plus_hour", df['test_time'] + expr('INTERVAL 1 HOURS'))
```

Comment: either add explanation or link to one - https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-add-hours-minutes-and-seconds-to-timestamp/