# Implement lambda function from python to pyspark-Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

**Python:**

I have a dataframe that I am applying a lambda function to check the conditions based on the values of a column.

```
In Pandas it looks like this(Example):

new_df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')

  lkey value_x rkey value_y col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 
0  foo     one  foo    five  0    1     3    0   5    
1  foo     one  foo     NaN  1    0     2    4   0    
2  bar     two  bar     six  2    6     3    0   0    
3  foo    five  foo    five  7    2     0    0   0    
4  foo    five  foo     NaN  2    0     0    0   0   
5  bbb    four  bar    two   0    0     0    0   0      

def get_final_au(row):
    if row['col5'] == 0: 
        if row['col4'] == 0: 
            if row['col3'] == 0: 
                if row['col2'] == 0: 
                    return 'NOT FOUND'
                else:
                    return row['col2']
            else:
                return row['col3']
        else:
            return row['col4']
    else:
         return row['col5']


new_df['col6'] = new_df.apply (lambda row: get_final_au(row),axis=1)


Expected Output:

  lkey value_x rkey value_y col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
0  foo     one  foo    five  0    1     3    0   5    5
1  foo     one  foo     NaN  1    0     2    4   0    4
2  bar     two  bar     six  2    6     3    0   0    3
3  foo    five  foo    five  7    2     0    0   0    2
4  foo    five  foo     NaN  2    0     0    0   0   Not FOUND
5  bbb    four  bar    two   0    0     0    0   0   Not FOUND
```

**Pyspark:**

How would I do something similar in Pyspark?

new_df = new_df.withColumn('col6', **?**)

I have tried this but getting error. Please suggest

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
def get_final_au(row):
    if row['col5'] != 0:
        return row['col5']
    elif row['col4'] != 0:
        return row['col4']
    elif row['col3'] != 0:
        return row['col3']
    elif row['col2'] != 0:
        return row['col2']
    else:
        return 'NOT FOUND'
UDF_NAME = udf(lambda row: get_final_au(row), StringType())
new_df.withColumn('col6', UDF_NAME('col5','col4','col3','col2')).show(2,False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use UDF function OR **when** clause.
**when** clause will be easier.

Syntax will be like this for **UDF**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def function_name(arg):
    # Logic
    # Return value

# Register the UDF
UDF_NAME = udf(function_name, ArgType())

df.select(UDF_NAME('col').alias('new_col'))
```

for **when** clause

```
    df.withColumn("new_column", when(condition1, value).when(condition2, value).otherwise(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of: [Apply a function to a single column of a csv in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977625/apply-a-function-to-a-single-column-of-a-csv-in-spark)

**Suggestion:**

Modify `get_final_au` to this

```py
def get_final_au(row):
    if row['col2'] != 0:
        return row['col2']
    elif row['col3'] != 0:
        return row['col3']
    elif row['col4'] != 0:
        return row['col4']
    elif row['col5'] != 0:
        return row['col5']
    else:
        return 'NOT FOUND'
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you please suggest do i need to call the above modified function like this in pyspark dataframe as it is giving error: new_df = new_df.withColumn('col6', udf(lambda row: get_final_au(row)))

Answer (score 0):

udfs are the last resort. they are quite slow. Can come with the same outcome using the following

```
cols=[ 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4','col5']
new_df.select(*[when(col(x)==0,'NOT FOUND').otherwise(col(x)).alias(x) for x in cols]).show()
```